# Processing on Tablet

Tags: processing, tablet

Can I somehow make my processing sketches work on some Tablet PCs or Smartphones?

For example on a Windows Surface Tablet or on a Windows Phone or an Android device? I guess it is harder for iOS devices.

If yes, could I even put the touchscreen to good use?

Answer (score 1):

For Android, it's easy. See: [Processing wiki page for Android.](http://wiki.processing.org/w/Android)

For iOS, it's more difficult due to Apple's security settings. However, I did find this: [iProcessing.](http://luckybite.com/iprocessing/)

For Windows, I found this app: [ProcessingJS Reader.](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/store/app/processingjs-reader/734ea3b3-d4db-46c3-b46c-45131fb748af)

And finally yes, you can use the touchscreen.